# как это сделать?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image: макет]

вот это view, где коризна, оно выдивигается по нажатию на кнопку и прячется свайпом ну или потянуть вниз просто, как это реализовать на ios, что нужно использовать подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите это видео! Оно должно вам помочь .
[Video: Slide menu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cA85wADo_9s)

Comment: Спасибо огромное)